# SQL insert with empty value for the id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

How do I insert a sql row into a new table where it meets criteria but resets the id value. In other words, copy the row, but reset the id value.

This is my current sql

```
INSERT INTO followers_lost SELECT * FROM followers WHERE pk = $pk
```

I tried to SET id=null and VALUE (0), but both don't work.

Comment: By ID do you mean an identity column? Are you wanting a new row with a new identity value? Can you provide the schema of the table ?

Comment: @JBdev I am trying to move a row from one table to the other one without copying the ID entry. Yes, it is the identity column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do since you want all the columns except the identity is specify all the non-identity columns on the insert:

```
INSERT INTO [followers_lost] ([Column1],[column2]...{but not the identity 
column})
SELECT [Column1],[column2]...{but not the identity column} FROM followers WHERE 
pk = $pk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the column and then update it:

```
SET @new_id=0;
UPDATE your_table
SET id = @new_id := @new_id + 1
where id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

OK based on your comment I think you are trying to take all or some of the fields from Followers except the PK and put them into Followers_Lost where they equal a certain PK. If you want multiple PK's you would need to change the where clause to an IN statement instead of an equal and adjust your values accordingly.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UAT_Followers_Lost (PK INT IDENTITY(1,1),DATA VARCHAR(50) )
CREATE TABLE dbo.UAT_Followers (PK INT IDENTITY(1,1),DATA VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO dbo.UAT_Followers 
(DATA)
SELECT 'Jan' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Feb'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mar'

DECLARE @PK INT
SET @PK = 1


INSERT INTO dbo.UAT_Followers_Lost
(Data)
SELECT Data 
FROM dbo.UAT_Followers
WHERE PK = @PK
```

Comment: I am trying to move a row from one table to the other one without copying the ID entry.

Comment: The key to what you are trying to do is you have to qualify all the fields that you are wanting to insert into your table and make sure you qualify those same fields in the select statement that is putting data in your fields.

Comment: Hi Ryan, not really. JBdev's post above did solve my problem. Thanks for your help though